# IIS rewrite rules using {C:n} as input

Tags: .net, apache, iis, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I'm trying to rewrite **url only in case** part of the queryString present in the path as well
For example: 
This url: `http://www.mywebsite.com/func/api.ashx?method=func&p1=v1` is valid 
but this url `http://www.mywebsite.com/path/api.ashx?method=func&p1=v1` will not be rewriten.

So far this is what I have:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Name1" enabled="true">
                <match url="^(.+)" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="method=([^&amp;]*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/(.*)\/" />
                    <add input="{{C:1}}" pattern="{{C:2}}" /> <!-- this is not working -->
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/api.ashx" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Is this can be done? whats the best way to check if method is part of the path assuming the value is dynamic.

BTW - I tried using groups in my patterns `method=(?<methodName>[^&amp;]*)` IIS don't like it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can't do this in IIS. Because regex expression is not supported in "input" attribute and "{" is not support in "pattern" attribute.  So we can't find a way to match two capture group.

You may need only do this in code level.